# How do I join this table in KSQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'm streaming a few tables from MS SQL Server into Kafka using CDC and the Debezium connector.  One of the SQL tables is represented in KSQL as a stream and the rest are KSQL tables that I want to join to the stream to enrich the data, so I have a chain of KSQL streams each joining a new KSQL table to the output of the previous KSQL stream in the chain.

Let A be a KSQL stream.
Let B through D be KSQL tables.
A + B = A'
A' + C = A''
A'' + D = A'''

This works just fine for A' and A'', but A''' is giving me the error: `Source table (D) key column (X) is not the column used in the join criteria (Y).`  Why am I able to produce streams A' and A'' without incident but A''' gives me this error?

I found some SO questions that indicated I should rekey D using the PARTITION BY clause, but that causes another error: `mismatched input 'PARTITION' expecting ';'`.  Seems like `CREATE TABLE` doesn't play nice with `PARTITION BY`, and if I use `CREATE STREAM` instead, it tells me I can't create a stream from a table and should use `CREATE TABLE`.

HALP!

**UPDATE:** Obfuscated query added.

```
CREATE STREAM A_Enriched_Phase7
WITH(PARTITIONS=1)
AS
SELECT *
FROM A_Enriched_Phase6 a
    JOIN KsqlTableD d ON a.X = d.X
PARTITION BY a.ID;
```

Comment: Can you also share the KSQL query?

Answer (score 1):

A few things here, and harder to answer without your full set of source SQL statements.

1. When you join to a table in KSQL, the join is carried out on the *key of the message*.
2. When you create a table in KSQL you can use the `WITH (KEY='col_foo'` syntax to inform KSQL that a field in the schema *has the same value as the key*. What you are not doing is instructing KSQL to key the messages using the `col_foo` field.

So let us imagine that your table is defined thus:

```
ksql> CREATE TABLE KsqlTableD (COL1 VARCHAR, X VARCHAR, Y VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='D', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', PARTITIONS=1, KEY='Y');

 Message
---------------
 Table created
---------------
```

Insert some data:

```
ksql> INSERT INTO KsqlTableD (COL1, X, Y) VALUES ('A','B','C');
```

Now try to join on a column *that is not the key column of the table*:

```
ksql> SELECT A.*,D.* FROM MYSTREAM A LEFT JOIN KsqlTableD D ON A.COL1=D.X;
Source table (D) key column (D.Y) is not the column used in the join criteria (D.X). Only the table's key column or 'ROWKEY' is supported in the join criteria.
Statement: SELECT A.*,D.* FROM MYSTREAM A LEFT JOIN KsqlTableD D ON A.COL1=D.X;
Caused by: Source table (D) key column (D.Y) is not the column used in the join
    criteria (D.X). Only the table's key column or 'ROWKEY' is supported in the join
    criteria.
```

So you need to either join on the key column:

```
ksql> SELECT A.*,D.* FROM MYSTREAM A LEFT JOIN KsqlTableD D ON A.COL1=D.Y;
1565700762038 | 1 | 1 | FOO | null | null | null | null | null
```

Or you need to rekey your table data and then join on it:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM D WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='D', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
ksql>
ksql> CREATE STREAM D_REKEY AS SELECT * FROM D PARTITION BY X;

 Message
----------------------------
 Stream created and running
----------------------------
ksql> CREATE TABLE D_X WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='D_REKEY', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', KEY='X');

 Message
---------------
 Table created
---------------
ksql> SELECT A.*,D.* FROM MYSTREAM A LEFT JOIN D_X D ON A.COL1=D.X;
1565700762038 | 1 | 1 | FOO | null | null | null | null | null
```